# How to compare current date and last modified date in Android?

Tags: android, date

I want to compare the two dates. If exceeds more then 24 hrs then I want to do some action.

I am getting file's last modified date using this piece of code:

```
 Date lastModDate = new Date(filename.lastModified());
 Log.d("Date", "File last modified @ : " + lastModDate.toString());
```

It is coming in the given below format:

```
Mon Aug 17 11:07:02
```

So my question is, in which format I need to get the current date and how to compare with difference in hours?

Comment: check with condition System.currentTimeMillis()-lastRestoredMillis>= AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY

Comment: Your question has some spelling and grammatical issues. I have edited it. kindly accept the review.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
long diff = (new Date().getTime() - filename.lastModified().getTime()) / 60 / 60 / 24;

if (diff > 24)
    //do something
```

Comment: Thank you so much Almis . its saved my time lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Date getDateFromString(String mSelectedDate) throws ParseException {
            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss");
            return simpleDateFormat.parse(mSelectedDate);
}
```

Using the method above you can get the string parse to the date format. Once you have the date object, I thing you can figure out how to compare it.

Answer (score 0):

long diff = (new Date().getTime() - file.lastModified().getTime()) / 60 / 60 / 24;
use #almis given code and 
then check difference is less then 24 hours covert it to minute and then covert second format . you found actual difference between two times . 
otherwise is difference is more then 24 hour covert into day . 
like :

```
if(diff>24){
 day= diff/24;
 diff%=24;
} //and then
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer in Kotlin :

```
val diffInHours = (Date().time - filename.lastModified()) / 1000 / 60 / 60

if (diffInHours > 24)
    //do something
```